# Python-telegram-bot How to send InlineKeyboard via url

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Trying to send message with callback keybord attached to it, bot no good. Tels me

```
TypeError: must be str, not ReplyKeyboardMarkup
```

Can't find any exemples how to do it correctly.

```
keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Выполнено", callback_data='Done')],
                [InlineKeyboardButton("MAC", callback_data='MAC'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton("Phone", callback_data='Phone'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton("История", callback_data='History')]]
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    requests.post(url='https://api.telegram.org/bot{blah}/'
                      'sendMessage?chat_id=' + str(query.message.chat_id) + '&text="TEST"&reply_markup=' + reply_markup)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should use `InlineKeyboardMarkup` instead of `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` to craete the markup object made of `InlineKeyboardButton`s.

Then, you probably should simply use the `bot` object to send the message with `bot.send_message(query.message.chat_id, 'TEST', reply_markup=reply_markup)`.

Lastly, if you really really need to use `requests` to do manual HTTP request, you should provide the parameters in the `requests.post()`'s `data`.

```
import json
import requests
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup

keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Выполнено", callback_data='Done')],
            [InlineKeyboardButton("MAC", callback_data='MAC'),
             InlineKeyboardButton("Phone", callback_data='Phone'),
             InlineKeyboardButton("История", callback_data='History')]]
reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

data = {"chat_id": query.message.chat_id,
        "text": "TEST", 
        "reply_markup": json.dumps(reply_markup.to_dict())}

requests.post(url='https://api.telegram.org/bot{blah}/sendMessage', data=data)
```